# C# Unity 2D Player Goes through Box Collider

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

i`ve got a problem with a player it has RigidBody2D,Box Collider2D
i`ve searched for 2days and no result had used a DontGoThroughThings, and lot of other things, Or maybe did something wrong. i`am making a mobile game and added to script a Input.touches

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
            {
                Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
                newPosition.y += touch.deltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = newPosition;
            }
```

And it Got Speed, when i move finger to fast object goes straight out of camera view and he didnt collide with a collider

sorry for bad english
Thanks for Your Advice
If need more info , i will give details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the problem is that your object is moving so quickly between frames that it completely misses the collider. You should clamp the maximum speed that your object can go to some reasonable range, rather than using the `touch.deltaPosition.y` directly. Something like this:

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
    newPosition.y += Mathf.Clamp(touch.deltaPosition.y * speed, MIN_SPEED, MAX_SPEED) * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for advice , it now doesnt go out of box collider , but it only goes up not down. Big thanks

Comment: @PeterisUlmanis you need to set MiN_SPEED as negative value to let the object go down.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with discrete physics simulation.

Copy/paste from this [link](https://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/06/01/when-bullets-move-too-fast/) in case the site dies:

> This phenomenon is called “tunneling”. Tunneling comes up when an
>   object is going so fast that the new updated position does not
>   intersect with the object it was heading towards.
>
> It is all really about scale. Tunneling will only occur if an object
>   is moving fast enough so that it can move the complete length of the
>   shortest width of another object in the time quantum of the
>   simulation.
>
> There are physics simulation libraries that perform continuous
>   collision detection (CCD) which will figure out if two objects
>   collided at any point within the simulation frame. Usually this is
>   accomplished by creating a new collision shape that has a volume which
>   contains all the space that the moving object occupied throughout the
>   time quantum. It then tries to figure out the intersection of the
>   movement volumes with other objects and then looks even closer to see
>   if the both objects existed at the intersection of their collision
>   volumes at the same time.